# Beacon Tools crash iOS

Tags: beacon, google-beacon-platform

I have some Beaconinside v2 beacons - one is working with Google Beacon Tools app on an iPhone 6S Plus.  WIth another I got something wrong and had to set the device as "decommissioned" in the dashboard.

Now the IOS app just crashes if I try and re-add that device - is this a known problem with the Beacon Tools app??

Comment: please state what's wrong more clearly.

Comment: When I try and add the beacon with google's beacon tools, I get to the screen where I am about to commit the addition of the new beacon and then beacon tols just crashes with no error message

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem. I sent a support request to Beaconinside in a similar matter and Cornelius Rabsch (CTO) confirmed to me that the Beacon Tool App is crashing a lot and that Beaconinside is talking with Google to improve this circumstance.